# Adding a lightbox using Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a lightbox using bootstrap, but when I click on the link to the lightbox nothing happends.

My HTML code is as follows:

```
 <head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href ="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Bootstrap RC1</title>
```

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12">`

            <h2>Bootstrap Lightbox - Creativity Tuts</h2>

            <div id="demolightbox" class="lightbox fade hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="lightbox-content">
                        <img src="images/beautiful-image.jpg">
                        <div class="lightbox-caption"><p>This is my background image</p></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
                <a data-toggle="lightbox" href='#demolightbox'><p>Open lightbox</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't like Bootstrap's [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) plugin?

Comment: Hey Phil how would I use the Model plugin to show the lightbox

Comment: Modal / lightbox, same thing. In any case, it looks like the *bootstrap-lightbox* plugin (v 0.6) isn't compatible with Bootstrap 3 due to changes made around the `hide` class. Also, your incorrect HTML nesting of a `<p>` inside an `<a>` isn't doing you any favours.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle which omits the `hide` class and fixes your HTML but it still has some problems - http://jsfiddle.net/BgLeb/

Answer (score 1):

I think you have used two jquery files in your code,

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I think you should use one at a time, and put this script above of rest of all the embeded scripts

Also two bootstrap files added to this code, only one is required. So remove one of below file from the code

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is put the ajax.googleapis.com... above all the other scripts, and it'll work!

Comment: Good catch but it's not the entire problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<html>
<head>   
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-lightbox/0.7.0/bootstrap-lightbox.css"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-lightbox/0.7.0/bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-lightbox/0.7.0/bootstrap-lightbox.min.css"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-lightbox/0.7.0/bootstrap-lightbox.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>   

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="span12">`

            <h2>Bootstrap Lightbox - Creativity Tuts</h2>

            <div id="demolightbox" class="lightbox fade hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="lightbox-content">
                        <img src="img_fjords.jpg"/>
                        <div class="lightbox-caption">
                          <p>This is my background image</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
                <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#demolightbox" class="span2 thumbnail">
                  <p>Open lightbox</p>
                  <img src="img_fjords.jpg"/>
                </a>

        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Follow this Example you can learn it easily 
[Lightbox](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_lightbox)